# Django + nginx + socket - url path not working

Tags: django, nginx

Whenever I try to go to `www.example.com/anything` it always redirects to `www.example.com`.

It works fine if I don't use the domain. Ex: `ip.ip.ip.ip/anything` works.

here's my sites-available

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my_ip_here;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/chris/Portfolio_v2/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your domain name to the server block

```
server_name www.example.com;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have fixed it. :(